# Flutter: Main Activity of Android project

Tags: flutter

I'm getting 'unresolved reference' for androidx and NonNull in the MainActivity(Android) whilst building my Flutter app. What is causing this and how do I fix it please?

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```